# How to delete last row in DataGridView and keep the row selected?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and this is not duplicated question, I checked similar questions here but not luck.

I have 2 buttons and `DataGridView1`. 
`ButtonAdd` to add a row and `buttonDelete` to delete a row.
First, I click Add to add new row and always keep the last row selected.

Second, when I want to delete the last row or any other rows (by clicking on them) it works perfect and the deleted row stays selected (as I wanted ).

Now I add a row then the last row is automatically selected and then when I want to delete the last row (without clicking on it but it is already selected) it gives me an error:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

But if I click on it, it works and the row stays selected.

So my problem is that I can not delete the last row without clicking on it (but the last row is actually already selected as result of adding row). I want to delete it and keep the row selected.
Please help, Thank you

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Int RowIndex;
    Int RowCount;
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, "pizaa", 3);  //add rows to dataGridView;
        dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Selected = true; //select the added row
    }    

    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        RowIndex = RowCount - 1;
        switch (RowCount)
        {
            case 0:     /// no Rows to delete
                break;
            case 1:    /// only one Row to delete
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                break;
            default:    // otherwise
               dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index); //delete the selected
               dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Selected = true;  //  select same row after deleting it.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the last row is deleted the number of rows is lowered by 1 so you cannot select the row with the same index of the row you deleted. the error is produced by the delete or by the select after the delete?

Comment: Paolo. I know and I though about that but I can delete the last row only when I click on it and the row stays selected (so it works perfect).  But if I don't click on it ( but it is already selected) I can not delete it.

Comment: I think that the responsible for the behaviour you don't want is the property `AllowUserToAddRows` (which you have presumably set to true). The peculiarity of this situation is that it shows a last row (for the user to input the information) which is not exactly considered as such. That is: you think that there is still a row remaining in the DataGridView, but this is not exactly the case. Set this property to false such that you have a perfectly-controlled situation (you might need to correct some parts of your code to avoid errors).

Comment: Do you need to select specific cells? Changing the `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect` works as you intend.

Comment: varocarbas. I agree with you but I already set AllowUserToAddRows to false but still did not work.

Comment: Chawin. I have already set SelectionMode to FullRowSelect when I created the DataGridView but still not working.

Comment: This code is not precisely perfect and saying something like "did not work" is not too clear. I guess that you are now getting an error when adding rows the first time (because `RowIndex` is -1). If you correct this issue (make sure that `RowIndex` is always >= 0 or don't select anything when it is < 0), it should work as you want.

Comment: varocarbas. not true. I don't have error when i add rows. when i delete rows  I have Switch statement to check number of rows. also when i add rows the RowIndex is incremented so the RowIndex never goes -1.

Comment: I meant after setting the aforementioned property to false. Anyway... as said this is not a good direction and you are not providing enough information. Additionally, SO is not meant for custom-solving your problems, but to provide comprehensive answers to problems which might be helpful to other people (certainly not the case here). So, I will stop helping in this question.

Comment: varocarbas. I am sorry but I thought I explained it well. I spent 30 mins to organize my question  and tried to put it in the best clear form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplishes your intent as I understand it. The private fields RowIndex and RowCount are unnecessary and have been removed. I've applied some non-default property values in the Form constructor so you can see them. Most notably there is a SelectionChanged event handler that determines whether or not the delete button is enabled.

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should keep you going in the right direction.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonDelete.Enabled = false;
        dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += dataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonDelete.Enabled = (((DataGridView)sender).SelectedRows.Count > 0);  
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, "pizaa", 3);  //add rows to dataGridView;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true; //select the added row
    }

    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index);

            // Select the last row if it exists...
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                index = (index == 0) ? 0 : --index;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a few additional notes are in order.

The dataGridView Rows Add() method returns the index of the row that was added. This is then used to select that index of the grid.

`index = (index == 0) ? 0 : index--;` is a shorthand "if" statement that means "if index == 0, then return 0, else decrease index by 1 and return the result.

Comment: S. Brentson. Thank you for you help, I will test it and tell you

Comment: it works good when you delete any selected row but when the last row is selected and you want to delete it, it shows error:  "Index was out of range" . I tried to change the code but no luck, any idea? thank you

Comment: Sorry for that. It was in my assignment of the index. I've corrected the syntax and also applied a couple other small fixes. See if the revised code works for you now.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help and explanations .